# How can I parse JSON with comments using System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I have some JSON that includes comments (even though comments aren't strictly allowed in the [JSON spec](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).)  How can I parse this JSON using `System.Text.Json`?

The JSON I have received is as folows:

```
// A person
{
    "Id" : 1 /* Person's ID */,
    "Name" : "Foo" // Person's name
}
```

When I attempt to load it into a `JsonDocument` like so:

```
using var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString);
```

I get the following exception:

> ````
> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: '/' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
>    at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
>    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)```
> ````

And when I attempt to deserialize with `JsonSerializer`:

```
var person = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(jsonString);
```

I get a similar exception:

> ```
> System.Text.Json.JsonException: '/' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
>  ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: '/' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
>    at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
>    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)
> ```

How can I parse or deserialize this JSON with `System.Text.Json`?

Comment: Technically, it's not legal JSON, as the official JSON syntax doesn't support comments. Nevertheless, most JSON parsers have support for at least ignoring the comments.

Comment: Agreed.  Making support for comments be a non-default option is sensible since they're not in the official syntax.

Comment: there is nothing "official" in this world. comments are useful in json. end of story

Answer (score 36, accepted):

JSON containing comments can be parsed by `System.Text.Json`, but **by default such JSON is considered invalid**, likely since comments are not included in the [JSON standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259).  Support for comments nevertheless can be enabled by modifying the **[`JsonCommentHandling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsoncommenthandling?view=netcore-3.1)** enum in options:

> ```
> Disallow   0   Doesn't allow comments within the JSON input. 
>                Comments are treated as invalid JSON if found, and a JsonException is thrown. 
>                This is the default value.
>
> Skip       1   Allows comments within the JSON input and ignores them. 
>                The Utf8JsonReader behaves as if no comments are present.
>
> Allow      2   Allows comments within the JSON input and treats them as valid tokens. 
>                While reading, the caller can access the comment values.
> ```

To enable skipping or loading of comments when reading directly with [`Utf8JsonReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader?view=netcore-3.1), set [`JsonReaderOptions.CommentHandling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonreaderoptions.commenthandling?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonReaderOptions_CommentHandling) in one of the [`Utf8JsonReader` constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1), e.g. as follows:

```
static List<string> GetComments(string jsonString)
{
    var options = new JsonReaderOptions 
    { 
        CommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Allow 
    };
    var list = new List<string>();
    var reader = new Utf8JsonReader(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString)), options);
    while (reader.Read())
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Comment)
            list.Add(reader.GetComment());
    return list;
}
```

When parsing with `JsonDocument` set [`JsonDocumentOptions.CommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocumentoptions.commenthandling?view=netcore-3.0#System_Text_Json_JsonDocumentOptions_CommentHandling):

```
var options = new JsonDocumentOptions
{
    CommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip,
};
using var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString, options);
```

When deserializing with `JsonSerializer` set [`JsonSerializerOptions.ReadCommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.readcommenthandling?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_ReadCommentHandling):

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    ReadCommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip
};
var person = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(jsonString, options);
```

Note that, as of .NET Core 3.1, **`JsonDocument` and `JsonSerializer` only support skipping or disallowing of comments**; they do not support loading them.  If you try to set `JsonCommentHandling.Allow` for either, you will get an exception:

> ```
> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Comments cannot be stored in a JsonDocument, only the Skip and Disallow comment handling modes are supported. (Parameter 'value')
> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Comments cannot be stored when deserializing objects, only the Skip and Disallow comment handling modes are supported. (Parameter 'value')
> ```

(This means that one does not need to manually skip comments when writing a [`JsonConverter<T>.Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.read?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_Serialization_JsonConverter_1_Read_System_Text_Json_Utf8JsonReader__System_Type_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_) method, which simplifies comment processing as compared to Newtonsoft where comments are exposed to [`ReadJson()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm) and must be checked for every time a token is read.)

For more see *[How to serialize and deserialize JSON in .NET : Allow comments and trailing commas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?view=netcore-3.1#allow-comments-and-trailing-commas)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WDcNIL).